# Why is my Rigid Body simulation giving weird results?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I've made a scene with Blender with a bumpy soil. So,to put some objects on my scene, I decided to put them in the air and let them fall, using a rigid body simulation. The problem is that when I press alt+A, my chair that I had put in the air **goes right (first frame) and goes down for 3 frames and stops there.** About four objects of my scene do the same thing.

I tried many things and went on many forums and I didn't find an answer to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the objects are not scaled (Object>Apply>Scale shortcut `Ctrl+A`) because that can cause issues. Very small objects (about 0.01 blender units) may require tweaked settings.